# Android Stream Video From PC

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

im interested in writing an Android program that plays video stream from a local PC on my network. Ive had a look at the API's and understand the principle behind the code.

What i was interested in is the media server on the PC side, does anybody have any experience with this? What software is best to use to stream the video? Ive had a look around and i can see its possible to use VLC but wasnt sure about any other options.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible to do it just using IIS at the PC end if the player on your Android device can play whatever format your video is in.

Comment: If you're talking about this one http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.gmail.traveldevel.android.vlc.app why invent a wheel or you want to add extra stuff ther?

Comment: Its actually for a university project im working on. Im trying to provide added functionality to an existing project. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

I would try PS3 media server on PC side. It's major purpose is to watch videos and listen to music on PS3 directly from PC. It uses VLC and MPlayer to stream videos and music. It supports various media players besides PS3.
http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/

I was thinkg about similar app as yours :) But on other platform. Sometimes I want to watch videos directly from PC on mobile, but there is no app for that yet.

Jack

Comment: Thanks for replying Jack, i actually already use PS3 media server to stream stuff to my ps3 but totally forgot that could be an option. I think i'll play around with both